# Is there any convenient way to warm water-based products to room temperature at home?

Tags: physical-chemistry, water, heat, temperature

When it's cold outside, some household water-based products (liquid soaps, wet wipes) become cold to the touch as well. Since these products are used directly on the skin, their coldness may cause discomfort to the user (especially babies and the elderly).

I am wondering if there is any convenient way to warm these products **at least** to room temperature of 23-25°C to reduce the discomfort. I am guessing the main obstacle is water's relatively high specific capacity (at 15°C, it is approximately 4.19 J/g∙°C, according to [this table](https://syeilendrapramuditya.files.wordpress.com/2011/08/water_specific_heat_capacity_vs_temperature.gif?w=500&h=300), taken from [this blog entry](https://syeilendrapramuditya.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/water-thermodynamic-properties/)), which may also be influenced by other ingredients of the soap, but I'm not sure in which direction...

As a possible solution, I thought of putting hot water in some vessel and submerging the soap container in it. I haven't tried it yet, but I wonder how hot should the water be and how much water do I need (i.e. how deep should the container be submerged), when taking into account the volume of soap and the plastic container itself.

And there's still the issue of the wipes, which can't be submerged in water...

Repeating the question: **Is there any convenient way to warm water-based products to room temperature at home?**

Comment: Find a room. Put the objects to be warmed in the room. Wait.

Comment: Yes there is a convenient way: a microwave oven. Note, though, that it is pretty easy to overheat things to dangerous temperatures.

Comment: I think that is one of the reasons why most people, especially infants and the elderly, prefer to have their bathroom inside a building. It has something to do with rain as well, but let's not get carried away. Btw, most babies don't use soap directly, their parents put it in their hands first and warm it that way. Try it, it works. If I understand correctly, you want to heat soap while living outdoors? If you're stuck in a blizzard in the forest, I don't want to have to use cold soap after washing my hands, yes. Maybe carry them close to your body at all times instead of your backpack?

Comment: Breathe on it until its warm to the touch.

Comment: Thanks, @AMT, for your comment. Actually, I am not talking about the outdoors. Since bathrooms usually have a window facing outside, it might get pretty cold there when it's cold outside (even if the window is closed). This causes the soap to become cold as well...

Comment: Ok, there are some countries where heaters are not commonly used, I understand your question. But I don't think this is a chemistry question but an economic one. Is it cheaper to buy a heater and heat the room or to keep a small water bath at 25 °C degrees at all time. Get your local energy costs, find out what kind of equipment you can afford, consider the warm bathroom as a plus and then do the math. I don't think we can help you in any way better than you can yourself. Economists deal with this kind of math all the time, if you need help, consider writing in one of their forums.

Comment: Well, bringing the entire room/apartment to 25 celsius will surely take care of things. I was looking for something more... focused... The chemistry part is the thermochemistry angle - I came up with putting the soap in a vessel with hot water prior to taking a bath according to the commonly used zeroth law of thermodynamics. I was wondering if any of our physical chemists friends might have a better suggestion.

Comment: Oh btw think about professional massage people who solved this problem already. I think they heat their stuff up. Maybe ask one of them what exactly they are using.

Comment: When my kids were babies, you could buy a little heating pad made to go around a box of baby wipes to keep them warm to the touch. With a baby shower for a colleague coming up we went looking for one as a gift - nobody had them anymore. Not sure why - perhaps the fell out of favor, one got the wipes too hot (never microwave!), who knows. But, ours sure worked wonders...

Comment: http://engineering.mit.edu/ask/are-there-materials-can-absorb-heat-without-becoming-hot

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be more appropriately asked on Lifehacks.SE: http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/